# Find a subspace of $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^{64}$ with some conditions!

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

in order to solve a little problem that give me a friend, I have the following question: Is it possible to find a subspace $W$ of the $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-vector space $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^{64}$ such that:

$\bullet  \ e_1$ is in $W$

$\bullet  \ \mathrm{dim}(W)=58$

$\bullet$ all the elements with exactly two nonzero coefficients are outside of $W$.

Thanks a lot!

For the ones who are interested in the problem: You and a friend are prisoners. To get free, the warders play a game with you: You know that you are going to go the next day in another room, with a chess board and coins which show head or tail randomly on every square. Your kidnapper shows you under which coin the key of your prison is hidden. You have to turn over exactly one coin after you are leaving the room. After that, your friend comes in the room and has to find the key in one try. Which strategy can be used?

Comment: How does the number $58$ come out of this problem?

Comment: Well, I want to find the good square, in other words I want to give a number between 1 and 64. If I take my vector space modulo the subspace that I described, I get a group with 64 elements and in every equivalence class there is one of the 64 classic basis element. The addition with a classical basis element is the mathematical interpretation of "I turn of a coin". This is the Idea :)

Comment: As a hint to solving the problem (for which I have a solution if you are interested), you might find it helpful to solve this for the case of a $2 \times 2$ chessboard. In general, a winning strategy exists if and only if the number of squares on the board is a power of $2$.

Comment: So in other words, because $58 = 64 - \log_2(64)$.

Comment: Okay, I will try with the 2x2 chessboard. You mean, this way of solving the problem is not the same as yours?

Comment: No, my way of solving the problem is different, at least superficially. We can handle the $8 \times 8$ chessboard using the space $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^6$ directly.

Comment: In other words, rather than identifying each square with a *basis element* of $\Bbb Z_2^{64}$, I identified each with (necessarily linearly dependent) elements of $\Bbb Z_2^6$.

Comment: Hum... I don't really understand what you mean. At the end, I look at $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^{64}/W \cong (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^{6}$... So the same as you?

Comment: You're right; assuming you get something to work in your quotient space, it would probably be equivalent to what I have in mind. I don't see, however, what the idea is behind the elements with exactly two non-zero coefficients.

Comment: never mind, I see it now. Still, it is not clear to me that such a subspace necessarily exists.

Comment: This condition implies, that I cannot find two classical basis element in the same equivalence class. This would shows, that I can reach every other equivalence class by adding one basis element, in other words, by turning a coin. And yeah, I was not able to show it. In the easy case of a 2x2 chessboard it works, but I construct my subspace by hand, and my $W$ is to big for that.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, such a subspace exists. Let $f:\{0,\dots,63\} \to \{0,1\}^6$ denote the map for which
$$
f(k) = (f_0(k),\dots,f_5(k)) \iff k = \sum_{i=0}^5 f_i(k) 2^i.
$$
Let $W$ be the kernel of the map $\phi:\Bbb Z_2^{64} \to \Bbb Z_2^6$ defined by
$$
\phi(e_{k}) = f(k-1), \quad k = 1,2,\dots,64.
$$
We see that no two elements lie in the same equivalence class because $f(e_j) \neq f(e_k)$ whenever $j \neq k$.

Comment: Yes, it looks really nice, thank you very much!